# In Friends Season 5 (Slash Late Season 4), Why Do Monica and Chandler Feel the Need to Keep Their Secret?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

So, I've gotten to Season 5 in *Friends*, and

> Monica and Chandler have, of course, gotten together and are kinda a couple.

But what I don't get is why they feel the need to keep it secret. I mean... it's not like anybody else in the friend group has kept that kind of thing secret.

Is there something going on that would make their friends less okay with it? Does anybody know why aren't they comfortable letting their friends know? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taking into account how all initially started it's normal that they didn't tell anyone at the beginning. They didn't know what to think about it themselves. Their conversation in hospital, when Phoebe was in labour, in episode *The One Hundreth* can be seen as a beginning of a real relationship.

Later they still they refrain to tell anyone. They explain their reasons to Joey when he finds out two episodes later, in [The One With All the Kips](http://uncutfriendsepisodes.tripod.com/season5/505uncut.htm):

> Chandler: The reason we didn't tell anyone was because we didn't want
>   to make a big deal out of it.
>
> Joey: But it is a big deal!! I have to tell someone!
>
> (They both grab him and stop him.)
>
> Chandler: No-no-no-no-no! You can't!
>
> Monica: Please. Now, I know this is hard.
>
> Joey: It is. It hurts.
>
> Monica: We know. Please? Please?!  We just don't want to deal with
>   telling everyone, okay? Just promise you won't tell

So they were worried about the reaction of the rest of the gang and they decided to keep their secret until they felt that they were completely ready to reveal it. Perhaps they waited too long and it kind of backfired on them later, but I won't spoil too much, since I don't know how far in Season 5 you are.

Comment: also the writers were not very sure how the audience would react to this mondler thing. So they kept it as a secret in the show and when they got good response for Mondler this relationship was opened up infront of all the other friends.